# Bouncing Between Multi-Part Identifier Could Not Be Bound & Ambiguous Column Name

Tags: sql-server

I keep getting two error messages depending on what I try to do to fix them.

Firstly here is my code:

```
SELECT 
    ConsltNum AS 'Consultant Number', 
    COUNT(ConsltNum) AS 'Client Count', 
    AVG(Balance) AS 'Average'
FROM
    Client Cl
INNER JOIN 
    Consultant Cn ON Cl.ConsltNum = Cn.ConsltNum
GROUP BY 
    Cn.LastName
```

Upon running it, I get this.

> Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
>   Ambiguous column name 'ConsltNum'.
>
> Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
>   Ambiguous column name 'ConsltNum'.

Now, I know it is ambiguous because the `ConsltNum` exists in both tables I've included. Normally I'd try and dial into that database by changing the code to this:

```
SELECT 
    Client.ConsltNum AS 'Consultant Number', 
    COUNT(Client.ConsltNum) AS 'Client Count', 
    AVG(Balance) AS 'Average'
FROM
    Client Cl
INNER JOIN 
    Consultant Cn ON Cl.ConsltNum = Cn.ConsltNum
GROUP BY 
    Cn.LastName
```

Upon running this, I get:

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
>   The multi-part identifier "Client.ConsltNum" could not be bound.
>
> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
>   The multi-part identifier "Client.ConsltNum" could not be bound.

A few other things worth mentioning: I've tried dialling to `dbo.Client.ConsltNum` and it throws the same error.

Answer (score 2):

Just use the right alias:

```
SELECT cl.ConsltNum AS Consultant_Number,
       COUNT(*) AS Client_Count, AVG(?.Balance) AS Average
FROM Client Cl INNER JOIN
     Consultant Cn
     ON Cl.ConsltNum = Cn.ConsltNum
GROUP BY cl.ConsltNum;
```

The `?` is for the the alias of the table where `balance` comes from.

Notes:

- You need to use the table alias assigned for the column.
- The `GROUP BY` should match the `SELECT` column.
- Only use single quotes for string and date constants.  Give columns names that don't need to be escaped.
- You might was well use `COUNT(*)`, because you know `ConsltNum` is never `NULL`.